# Using Getters and Setters in Base Activity Android

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity

I made a generic activity which I am extending from in my main activity.

I want to be able to change the String Variable in the base activity.

See below.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sidedrawer);

        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        tv.setText(getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And in the class i'm extending this from.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String name="Jim";
        super.setName(name);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

However I am getting a null exception for the String name when I am setting the text of the TextView. I thought this would would as I am calling super.setName() before super.onCreate()? Can anyone help me on this? I am just using this as an example for more complex problems. Any help is much apppreciated

Comment: dude give some time to understand abstraction.

Comment: you can directly call setName() but user after onCreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tv.setText(getName());
```

write the above line in setName(-) as follows

```
public void setName(String name) {
   tv.setText(name);
}
```

and remove getter in `BaseActivity`

And in `onCreate`() of `MainActivity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String name="Jim";
    super.setName(name);
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 String name="Jim";
 super.setName(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because name is null and setText(null) throws Exception. Try-

```
public String getName() { 
    if(name == null)
       return "";

    return name;
}
```

and

```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   String name="Jim";
   super.setName(name);
```